# Error message when try to create a new Acumatica instance

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know what is the meaning of the following screenshot. ??

[image]

I got this error message whan I try to create new instance of acumatica erp system in version 2017 R2.

thanks

Comment: What version of Windows do you have on your machine?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional SP 1

Answer (score 0):

This error may be on an old version of Windows. You have nothing to worry about if you don't use push notification feature.
If you want to use it, you have to install MSMQ manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/installing-message-queuing-msmq#to-install-message-queuing-40-on-windows-7-or-windows-vista

Comment: I followed these steps, restarted, and still get the error when trying to install an Acumatica 2018 R2 instance. I am attempting to set up the push notifications, so this is an important, necessary feature for my needs. Currently, clicking OK and finishing the installation does not allow me to use the features, of course. Anyone have any solution?